# Reinstated checkboxes in site analytics now shows 4 boxes instead of 2

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderator-tools, analytics

Now that checkboxes have been reinstated on the moderator analytics page, the number of checkboxes has doubled from 2 to 4.

I assume that someone was maybe attempting to rename them but forgot to remove the old ones?

[image]

Even crazier is the Questions and Answer chart which has gone from 2 to 6.

[image]

From https://chinese.stackexchange.com/admin/analytics

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is by design: you can toggle questions and answers separately.

This is perhaps not the best design though: given that there are at most 6 items (for voting: accept/up/down times raw/average), the “Include Raw Data” and “Include Moving Average” checkboxes are overcomplicating things.

For the case of items with a single number, such as the number of visits, the two sets of checkboxes are indeed fully redundant.

Answer (score 0):

As we established in another thread, I tend to look at one or the other (raw or averaged) data, so I kinda like having the original checkboxes still around for convenience.

If you don't want to toggle individual series, you can safely ignore the "extra" ones.

That said, there are more changes to analytics coming. We're going at it incrementally, so the design might change further later on.

Comment: Would be good if moderators were consulted in the process or at least given a heads up when changes are coming so we can comment. In our original discussion you mentioned that there was no need to have checkboxes, now we have double the checkboxes.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 I was thinking that all this stuff would be entirely uncontroversial. That'll teach me to assume. :) The analytics section hasn't been updated in a very long time, so it's understandable that everyone's used to it the way it is. I admit that this round of updates is motivated a lot by what we'd like to see internally since we also use these charts, but we do likely use them differently than the mods, so where it clearly breaks your workflow, let us know like you did with the radio button change (thanks!). Otherwise, please give the changes a chance.